# Odds $k$ people out of $m$ are from the same city

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A country has $n$ cities, with different amounts of people. The chance a person is from city $j$ is $p_j$, and we have a room of $m$ people.

I am interested in the probability $k$ people in the room are from the same city.

Now, suppose that $\frac{m}{k} < 2$. Then in this simple case, we can't have that $k$ people are from one city and a different set of $k$ people from a different city at the same time.

In this simple case, the probability is $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{m}{k}p_j^{k}(1-p_j)^{m-k}$$

But if $\frac{m}{k}\geq2$ then we need to do an inclusion-exclusion type argument which I find a bit difficult.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "$k$ people in the room are from the same city"? Do you mean, exactly $k$ people but not more than $k$, or do you mean, at least $k$ people?

Comment: @AdamRubinson exactly $k$.

Comment: And to clarify further, do you mean, what's the probability there are $k$ people in the room from the same city, or that $k$ randomly chosen people in the room will be from the same city? I presume it is the former, but just want to make sure.